# How to install FASTQC on home space as I do not have access to the root server

Tags: linux, java, download, bioinformatics

I am trying to run FASTQC on some data. I am working on a server where I do not have root access. Does anyone know a way where I can install fastqc in my home space as I don't have root on the server and unzip the file?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`conda`](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html) to install `fastqc`. I prefer to use separate `conda` environments for separate tools, but YMMV. If `bioconda` is not included in your channels, add it permanently, or add this to the commands below: `-c bioconda`.

**Examples:**

```
# Install the most recent version of fastqc in environment 
# called also "fastqc" (or use a different name):

conda create -n fastqc fastqc

# Install a specific version of fastqc into its own environment:

conda create -n fastqc-0.11.9 fastqc=0.11.9
```